# How to find the conjugate for a radical with a negative coefficient?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The convention for a conjugate is to change the sign in the middle, but there appear to be two conjugates in this case that yield different values. For example we could write this as:

$$\sqrt{b}-a \rightarrow \sqrt{b}+a$$

Or it could be $$-\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} \rightarrow -\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$

Which one is considered to be correct and why?

Comment: Algebra courses introduce "conjugates" simply to name pairs of binomials whose product is a "difference of squares". We typically see the conjugate of $a+b$ given as $a-b$ —changing "the sign in the middle— but these could be written $b+a$ and $-b+a$. So, technically, changing *either* sign is okay, although circumstances may suggest a *preferred* option. Note: In the realm of complex numbers, there's no choice: "the" conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$ (not $-a+bi$), with the sign change *strictly* applied to the imaginary part (so that the product of conjugates is guaranteed to be non-negative).

Comment: @Blue if both of these conjugates are technically correct then why do we get different answers when we multiply them?

Comment: Being *technically correct* doesn't being *equal*. :) ... Let's look at a typical scenario where conjugates help eliminate square roots: What is "the" conjugate of $-1+\sqrt{17}$? The Change-the-Middle-Sign Rule suggests $-1-\sqrt{17}$; my personal bias for simplicity prefers $1+\sqrt{17}$. Now: $(-1+\sqrt{17})(-1-\sqrt{17})=-16$, and $(-1+\sqrt{17})(1+\sqrt{17})=16$. The results don't match in numerical value, but they *do* match in the property of *not involving a square root*, which was the goal. Ultimately, (outside of stricter contexts such as complex numbers) there is no "the" conjugate.

Comment: That makes sense, but what if we had to simplify some kind of equation? Which conjugate do we select in that case?

Comment: Consider simplifying $3/(-1+\sqrt{17})$ using the two conjugate from my previous comment:$$\begin{align}\frac{3}{-1+\sqrt{17}}\cdot\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{-1-\sqrt{17}}=\frac{3(-1-\sqrt{17})}{-16}&=-\frac3{16}(-1-\sqrt{17})=\frac{3}{16}(1+\sqrt{17})\\
\frac{3}{-1+\sqrt{17}}\cdot\frac{\phantom{-}1+\sqrt{17}}{\phantom{-}1+\sqrt{17}}=\frac{3(\phantom{-}1+\sqrt{17})}{16}&=\phantom{-}\frac{3}{16}(\phantom{-}1+\sqrt{17})
\end{align}$$ The same result! Notice: The two conjugates are negatives of each other, and thus so are their products w/ $-1+\sqrt{17}$; the negatives cancel during simplification.

Comment: Really, the only danger in the ambiguity is a situation where someone has somehow *declared* one conjugate to be "correct" —say, according to the Middle-Sign Rule— so that you'll be deemed "incorrect" by choosing the other. (Nevermind that commutativity makes the "Middle-Sign Rule" ill-defined.) So, *know your audience*. :) ... In case my earlier comments get deleted, I'll note again that, in stricter contexts such as the complex numbers, the danger vanishes because there's an unambiguous way to determine which sign to change in a conjugate.